# How to append branch name and commit to git archive output file?

Tags: git, git-archive

I'am using git archive to create a zip file with latest version/HEAD but would like to add the branch name and the commit to the zip filename. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sha1=`git rev-parse --short --verify HEAD`
branch=`git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`

git archive -o latest_${branch}_${sha1}.zip HEAD
```

Call it `git-auto-archive`, for example, make it executable, put in your path, and run it with

```
git auto-archive
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of [CharlesB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11343/charlesb)'s [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986195/6309), make sure yo use Git 2.20+ (Q4 201), because `git archive -o latest_${branch}_${sha1}.zip` can produce a *tar* file instead of a zip one (bug which has been fixed), if use for a `--remote` repo.

See [commit 00436bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00436bf1b1c2a8fe6cf5d2c2457d419d683042f4) (25 Oct 2018) by [Josh Steadmon (``)](https://github.com/).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a5ab66e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5ab66ee5f36fa3e90955f36f6451b3cf67943ed), 06 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### archive: initialize archivers earlier
>
> Initialize archivers as soon as possible when running `git archive`.
>   Various non-obvious behavior depends on having the archivers initialized, such as determining the desired archival format from the provided filename.
>
> Since [08716b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08716b3c11f4899c1be046eca735761b30ca686d) ("`archive`: refactor file extension format-guessing",
>   2011-06-21, Git v1.7.7-rc0), archive_format_from_filename() has used the registered
>   archivers to match filenames (provided via `--output`) to archival
>   formats.
>
> However, when `git archive` is executed with `--remote`, format detection happens before the archivers have been registered.
>   This causes archives from remotes to always be generated as TAR files, regardless of
>   the actual filename (unless an explicit `--format` is provided).
>
> This patch fixes that behavior; archival format is determined properly
>   from the output filename, even when `--remote` is used.